# spring data elasticsearch 3.0.0 and spring data commons

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-data-commons

I am using spring data elasticsearch snapshot version (3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

If I use ElasticsearchTemplate, I'm getting an error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V`

Because in spring-data-commons-2.0.0BUILD-SANPSHOT & spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, call org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V !

But there is no such a method in springframwork 4.3.10-REALEASE :(

How can I solve this collision?

Comment: solved problem by myself :)
By upgrading spring version :(